# Value outside foreach

Tags: magento-2.1, php, checkout

Need value outside foreach

My code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();

foreach($items as $item) {
   $pid = $item->getProductId();
   $pdt_price = $item->getPrice();
   $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
   $gira = round($customProduct->getData('giracoin'));
   $fiat = round($customProduct->getData('fiatcurrency'));
   $giracoin = $pdt_price * $gira/100;
   $fiatcurrency = $pdt_price * $fiat/100;
}

echo $giracoin;
echo $fiatcurrency;
```

I am using Magento 2.

I want the output like this.

product 1 => giracoin : 10
             fiat currency:20

product 2 => giracoin : 10
             fiat currency:20

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you modifying for this? To me it looks like your going to end up with the wrong value if you echo outside the loop. You need to know which product your getting the 'giracoin' data for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you set `echo` inside foreach loop or you store the data in an array for later output:

```
$result = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    ...
    $result[$pid] = array(
        'giracoin' => $giracoin,
        'fiatcurrency' => $fiatcurrency 
    );
}

foreach ($result as $productId => $data) {
    echo "Product {$productId} => giracoin: {$data['giracoin']} fiat currency: {$data['fiatcurrency']}";
}
```

Comment: if i put it inside foreach loop the result will be like this -> http://prntscr.com/g3q6qi

Comment: @SUBINCHANDRAN is there any other loop that `echo` is called two times?

Comment: yes..there is another loop..that is listing the products..

Comment: Then reorder your code so that `$result` is generated outside this other loop.